# How to find out the Leap Year in My SQL using while loop

Tags: mysql

I am stuck in this question can anyone help me out

> Use the statement " while " to complete this Find out what leap years
> will be between 2020 and 2050 (leap year algorithm: divisible by 4 and not by
> 100, or by 400).
> Please define a function "fun_
> Leap_ YourName ", which can output all eligible
> years according to two years as function parameters.**

Results should be like this

```
2020 2024 2028 2032 2036 2040 2044 2048
```

I am not able to create query for this question.

What I did, I am sharing you but it is not what this question is asking. I am new to mySQL so have no idea.

```
delimiter //
drop function if exists fun_Leap_Murtaza;
create function fun_Leap_Murtaza(a int)
returns int
DETERMINISTIC
no sql
begin
  while (a <= 2020 ) do

set a = a + 4;
    

    end while;

return a;
end; //
delimiter;

SELECT fun_Leap_Murtaza (2020)
```

Comment: Btw the while should be a <2050...

Comment: @Akina the question's requirement is to create a function..

Comment: I realise that the assignment expressly requests this, but just to observe, this isn't what a relational database is for.

Comment: yeah i know but function suppose to have two inputs  one 2020 and other 2050 and then it compute and get all the leap years between them... @LelioFaieta

Comment: @Strawberry so how i solve this now :(

Comment: set `a=2020` (the start) and then `while (a <= 2050 ) do` that means: starting from 2020 execute what is inside the while section untill a becomes 2050. This means that in your while you have to put `a=a+1` at the end of your logic. It will iterate each year between 2020 and 2050 and you can perform your query against each year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION list_leap_years (first_year INT, last_year INT)
RETURNS TEXT 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
-- declare the variable where leap years will be collected for output
DECLARE output TEXT DEFAULT '';
WHILE first_year <= last_year DO
    -- test does the next day for "Feb, 28" is "Feb, 29"
    IF DAY(CONCAT(first_year, '-02-28') + INTERVAL 1 DAY) = 29 THEN
        -- if true - add this year to the list
        SET output := CONCAT(output, ',', first_year);
    END IF;
    -- increase the year for testing on the next cycle
    SET first_year := first_year + 1;
END WHILE;
-- return collected years
RETURN SUBSTRING(output FROM 2);
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e791b4b6aa30a6272364101907dcf9cb)

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Leap_year#C.23) for algorithms, and possible implementations. Based on the c implementation, here you go:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_is_leap_year;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION fn_is_leap_year(var_year INT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    RETURN (NOT(var_year % 4) AND var_year % 100 OR NOT(var_year % 400));
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And use it in accordance with the actual specification:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fun_Leap_YourName;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION fun_Leap_YourName(var_start_year INT, var_end_year INT)
RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
    DECLARE var_year INT DEFAULT var_start_year;
    DECLARE var_result TEXT DEFAULT '';
    WHILE (var_year <= var_end_year) DO
        IF (fn_is_leap_year(var_year)) THEN
            SET var_result := CONCAT(var_result, ' ', var_year); 
        END IF;
        SET var_year := var_year + 1;
    END WHILE;
    RETURN var_result;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Finally, call it like:

```
SELECT fun_Leap_YourName(2020, 2050);
```

Comment: I tried this but it gave error FUNCTION mysql.fn_is_leap_year does not exist, Time: 0.000000s...